# Float element goes into the next box

Tags: css, css-float

When I add float to the first element, it just goes inside the second block. What's the reason for this?

Check the fiddle here:
https://jsfiddle.net/peterzhong/33m7k5gy/9/

```css
.container {
  position:relative;
  width:10em;
  height:10em;
  background:#aaa;
  float:left;
}
.positioned {
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  bottom:0;
  right:0;
  background:#FFA500; 
}
.container1 {
  position:relative;
  width:10em;
  height:10em;
  background:#0092ff;
  margin-top:100px;
}
.positioned1 {
  position:absolute;
  top:75%;
  left:75%;
  bottom:-3em;
  right:-3em;
  background:#FFA500; 
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
   box1
   <div class="positioned"></div>
</div>
<div class="container1">
  box2
  <div class="positioned1"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: its expected behavior of `float`. whats your exact query.. how you wanna flow the divs?

Comment: Adding float:left to the container makes no difference in the fiddle. You are positioning absolutely within the parent div so that is why the yellow box is inside the grey. What do you actually want to happen? What is your goal?

Comment: I wanna align the two containers vertically like block-level element. I understand the absolute position part. but can't figure out why the first container goes into the second container if I add "float:left" property to the first one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your goal you have two different solutions here:

1. If you are willing to separate the two containers in different lines, you need to add `clear: both` property to `<div class="container1">` so it won't attach form left or right to any `floating` content.

```css
.container {
  position:relative;
  width:10em;
  height:10em;
  background:#aaa;
  float:left;
}
.positioned {
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  bottom:0;
  right:0;
  background:#FFA500; 
}
.container1 {
  position:relative;
  width:10em;
  height:10em;
  background:#0092ff;
  margin-top:100px;
  clear: both; /*Add this property*/
}
.positioned1 {
  position:absolute;
  top:75%;
  left:75%;
  bottom:-3em;
  right:-3em;
  background:#FFA500; 
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
   box1
   <div class="positioned"></div>
</div>
<div class="container1">
  box2
  <div class="positioned1"></div>
</div>
```

2. If you are willing to put both containers on the same line but NOT over each other, you will need to give `<div class="container1">` a `float` property too.

```css
.container {
  position:relative;
  width:10em;
  height:10em;
  background:#aaa;
  float:left;
}
.positioned {
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  bottom:0;
  right:0;
  background:#FFA500; 
}
.container1 {
  position:relative;
  width:10em;
  height:10em;
  background:#0092ff;
  /*margin-top:100px;*/ /* Margin top removed to give both containers same height */
  float: left; /* Add this property */
}
.positioned1 {
  position:absolute;
  top:75%;
  left:75%;
  bottom:-3em;
  right:-3em;
  background:#FFA500; 
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
   box1
   <div class="positioned"></div>
</div>
<div class="container1">
  box2
  <div class="positioned1"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You're welcome. If it was useful please feel free to mark it as answer so other visitors can find it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to clear the float of the second `div` ("`.container1`").

**Example:**

```
   .container {
        position: relative;
        width: 10em;
        height: 10em;
        background: #aaa;
        float: left;
    }

    .container1 {
        position: relative;
        width: 10em;
        height: 10em;
        background: #aaa;
        clear: both;
    }
```